# Get mouse co-ordinates continuously while mouse move onmousedown

Tags: c#, winforms

I can get mouse co-ordinates when mouse is down and up as

```
  private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseClickedX = e.X;
    mouseClickedY = e.Y;
}

   private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseReleaseX = e.X;
    mouseReleaseY = e.Y;
}
```

But I need the mouse co-ordinates continuously when mouse is down and move until mouse is up. I don't need co-ordinates when mouse move only but I need co-ordinates when mouse is down and move. How to do that?

**EDIT:**

```
   private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            while (isDragging) {
                mouseMoveX = e.X;
                mouseMoveY = e.Y;
                label1.Text = mouseMoveX.ToString();
                label2.Text = mouseMoveY.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I am using isDragging true or false onmosueup and down but this just hang the application. Should I use timer or thread?

Comment: Quick analysis: try changing the `while` to an `if`.

Comment: Yes, you must do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you should do:

1. Add to your class a private boolean field called `bool isDragging`
2. In the MouseDown handler, set `isDragging = true` and `this.Capture = true`
3. In the MouseUp handler, set `isDragging = false` and `this.Capture = false`
4. Add a MouseMove handler. In it, check `if (isDragging)` and if it is true, respond as you wish. Your MouseMove handler will be supplied with the current mouse coords.

The use of [`Capture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) is important, because otherwise you can lose MouseMove and MouseUp messages.

Comment: Please see the edit.  I am using isDragging true or false onmosueup and down but this just hang the application. Should I use timer or thread?

Comment: Change the `while` to an `if`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle `MouseMove` and check whether the mouse is down.